# How to get previous date in java

Tags: java, date

I have a String Object in format  **yyyyMMdd**.Is there a simple way to get a String with previous date in the same format?
Thanks

Comment: Not a direct answer but take a look a Joda Time. It's a really good date/time library for Java - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would rewrite these answers a bit.

You can use

```
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        // Get a Date object from the date string
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

        // this calculation may skip a day (Standard-to-Daylight switch)...
        //oneDayBefore = new Date(myDate.getTime() - (24 * 3600000));

        // if the Date->time xform always places the time as YYYYMMDD 00:00:00
        //   this will be safer.
        oneDayBefore = new Date(myDate.getTime() - 2);

        String result = dateFormat.format(oneDayBefore);
```

To get the same results as those that are being computed by using Calendar.

Comment: You'll only run into problems when DST disturbs. Your code may then return the same day.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to do it *without* Joda Time:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static String previousDateString(String dateString) 
            throws ParseException {
        // Create a date formatter using your format string
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        // Parse the given date string into a Date object.
        // Note: This can throw a ParseException.
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

        // Use the Calendar class to subtract one day
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

        // Use the date formatter to produce a formatted date string
        Date previousDate = calendar.getTime();
        String result = dateFormat.format(previousDate);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "20100316";

        try {
            // This will print 20100315
            System.out.println(previousDateString(dateString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid date string");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the code inside the try block doesn't even throw ParseException. You should limit its scope.

Comment: Makes for a slightly simpler example. That's the only reason I did it that way...

Comment: Thanks!
The example was useful.
I've used:
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
.
.

                        cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(strDate));
                        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
                        strDate= dateFormat.format( cal.getTime() );

Comment: Any specific reason you didn't use `Calendar.getInstance()`? To be on the safe side I would call `calendar.clear()` directly after constructing/getting it to avoid timezone clashes.

Comment: this methods seems to encounter problems with the input "00010101".

Comment: @BalusC I modified the example to use `getInstance()`. I just wasn't aware that method existed in `Calendar`, and I had always just used `GregorianCalendar`. Also, according to the documentation, `getInstance()` will return an instance using the default timezone and locale, so I'm not sure what the benefit of calling `clear()` would be in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vkraemer I think that qualifies as an edge case. In general, I think this solution works well :-)

Comment: @William: you're right wrt timezone, this is here indeed not the case.

Comment: If this is going to get called in a loop, you probably want to think about changing the scope of the objects that get created... like the Calendar object.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If you tell me why, maybe I can address your concerns.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
    Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
    //subtracting a day
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String result = s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Answer (score 6):

It's much harder than it should be in Java without library support.

You can parse the given String into a Date object using an instance of the [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) class.

Then you can use Calendar's [add()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) to subtract one day.

Then you can use SimpleDateFormat's [format() to](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) get the formatted date as a String.

The [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) a much easier API.

Answer (score 6):

**This is an old question, and most existing answers pre-date Java 8. Hence, adding this answer for Java 8+ users.**

---

Java 8 introduced new APIs for `Date` and `Time` to replace poorly designed, and difficult to use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes.

To deal with dates without time zones, `LocalDate` class can be used.

```
String dateString = "20200301";

// BASIC_ISO_DATE is "YYYYMMDD"
// See below link to docs for details
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

// get date for previous day
LocalDate previousDate = date.minusDays(1);

System.out.println(previousDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
// prints 20200229
```

Docs:

- [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE)
- [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: Best answer to this question since the release of Java 8...

Answer (score 4):

use SimpleDateFormat to parse the String to Date, then subtract one day. after that convert the date to String again.

Answer (score 2):

HI,

I want to get 20 days previous, to current date,

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar xdate = (Calendar)cal.clone();
xdate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, - 20);

System.out.println(" Current Time "+ cal.getTime().toString());
System.out.println(" X Time "+ xdate.getTime().toString());
```

I had some UN Expected result, When i tried on Jan 11th,

Current Time Tue Jan 11 12:32:16 IST 2011
 X Time Sat Dec 11 12:32:16 IST 2010

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar xdate = (Calendar)cal.clone();
xdate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,cal.getTime().getDate() - 20 );

System.out.println(" Current Time "+ cal.getTime().toString());
System.out.println(" X Time "+ xdate.getTime().toString());
```

This code solved my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the 3rd-party utility, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3 on Java 7. Takes just two lines.

```
String dateAsString = "20130101";
org.joda.time.LocalDate someDay =  org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyymmdd"));
org.joda.time.LocalDate dayBefore = someDay.minusDays(1);
```

See the results:

```
System.out.println("someDay: " + someDay );
System.out.println("dayBefore: " + dayBefore );
```

When run:

```
someDay: 2013-01-01
dayBefore: 2012-12-31
```

This code assumes you have no time zone. Lacking a time zone is rarely a good thing, but if that's your case, that code may work for you. If you do have a time zone, use a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object instead of [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).

About that example code and about Joda-Time…

```
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

// Joda-Time - The popular alternative to Sun/Oracle's notoriously bad date, time, and calendar classes bundled with Java 7 and earlier.
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

// Joda-Time will become outmoded by the JSR 310 Date and Time API introduced in Java 8.
// JSR 310 was inspired by Joda-Time but is not directly based on it.
// http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310

// By default, Joda-Time produces strings in the standard ISO 8601 format.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a generic method which takes

```
   - Date (String)  (current date or from date),
   - Format (String) (your desired fromat) and
   - Days (number of days before(-ve value) or after(+ve value))
```

as input and return your desired date in required format.

following method can resolve this problem.

```
public String getRequiredDate(String date , String format ,int days){
        try{
         final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date));
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java 8 we can use directly for this purpose

```
LocalDate todayDate = LocalDate.now();
```

By default it provide the format of 2021-06-07, with the help of formater we can change this also

```
LocalDate previousDate = todayDate.minusDays(5);
```

Comment: What you say is correct. The question seems to be about getting the day before some date string, not the day 1 or 5 days ago from today (not your downvoter).

Answer (score -3):

```
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
Date dt2 = new Date(cal2.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(dt2);
```