# How to get previous year from the result of current year in java?

Tags: java

```
public class CalendarCal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");
        String m = simpleDateformat.format(date);
        System.out.println("Year:" + m);
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100;
        System.err.println(year);
    }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the current year from this. How can I get the last (previous) year with help of utility? I don't want to do a calculation like `currentyear - 1` or like that.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458049/how-to-get-previous-date-in-java. I think it answer your questiion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use [`Calendar.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method to "add" `-1` to the year and wrap it in your own utility method:

```
private static int getPreviousYear() {
    Calendar prevYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    prevYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    return prevYear.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getPreviousYear());
}
```

**Prints on my system:**

```
2011
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.time.Year;

public class TryTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Year.now().minusYears(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as explained below:

```
//Create calendar instance
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();

//Set your date to it
    instance.setTime(date);

//Substract one year from it
    instance.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);

//Use the pattern you wish to display the date
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

// Convert the date to string using format method
    String previousYearDate = isoFormat.format(instance.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String previousDateString(String dateString) 
        throws ParseException {
    // Create a date formatter using your format string
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    // Parse the given date string into a Date object.
    // Note: This can throw a ParseException.
    Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

    // Use the Calendar class to subtract one day
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(myDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

    // Use the date formatter to produce a formatted date string
    Date previousDate = calendar.getTime();
    String result = dateFormat.format(previousDate);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class GetYear {
  public static void main(String []arg){
  Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
  int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1;
  System.out.println("Current Year: " + year );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Light weight solution (without direct or indirect constructor call of any Object).

```
   final class YearUtil {    

    static final int MILLIS_IN_SECOND = 1000;
        static final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
        static final int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;
        static final int HOURS_IN_DAY = 24;
        static final int DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365;
        static final long MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR = (long) MILLIS_IN_SECOND
                * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * MINUTES_IN_HOUR * HOURS_IN_DAY * DAYS_IN_YEAR;


        public static int getCurrentYear() {
            return (int) (1970 + System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR);
        }
    }
```

Than use it:

```
int prevYear = YearUtil.getCurrentYear() - 1;
```

These numbers are so big that there is no need to bother about even years (in your live and your childs childs childs...) ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4:

```
int year = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ).minusYears( 1 ).getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Calendar calendarEnd=Calendar.getInstance();

  // You can substract from the current Year to get the previous year last dates.
  calendarEnd.set(Calendar.YEAR,calendarEnd.get(Calendar.YEAR)-3);
  calendarEnd.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
  calendarEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,31);

  Date endDate=calendarEnd.getTime();

  System.out.println("\nEND Date Of this year : "+endDate);
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.